# Post not sent immediately with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

```
<script src="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<form>
<label>Campo</label>
<input id="campo" name="campo" placeholder="Campo" required="" type="text">
</form>  

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
            url: "control.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "campo=" + $("input#campo").val(),
            success : function(data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    $("#div").html("Campo non disponibile");
                }
                else {
                    $("#div").html("Campo disponibile :)");
                }
            }
            });
        });
</script>
```

I saw with Firebug that the POST contains the value of the input field is sent only updating the page and not immediately. Why?

Comment: What does "not immediately" mean? When is it sent? And why are you including two versions of jQuery on the page? Also, if you want to select an element by ID with `$("input#campo")` shouldn't you give the element an ID attribute?

Comment: What does "updating the page" mean?

Comment: As an aside, if you are going to build query strings by hand, then don't forget to escape your user input with `encodeURIComponent`, but don't build query strings by hand: `data: { campo: $("input#campo").val() },`

Comment: Why are you using Ajax to load content from "user input" as soon as the page has loaded? If you aren't going to actually wait for the user to input anything, you can just include the content on the page in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a proper click/submit handler registered for the form submission. Instead, you call `$.ajax` only on document ready. That's why you only see the submission on page load (or to be more accurate, document ready).

You need to listen to the submit event, so change your code to something like the following

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    …
    });
});
```

You don't need to wait for the document to be ready if your javascript is at the end of the page (it's always ready at that point). And I noticed that you include both v1.9 and v.1.10 of jQuery and that's generally not needed nor advisable.

Comment: This is right, but I want that when the user finish to write in the input there is immediatly the control to validate "campo"

Comment: @user3079616 That you need to listen for any `keyup` events on the input field in conjunction with a timeout so that you only sent the request at the end. But that wasn't part of your question, so please accept this answer and/or ask another question or clarify your question accordingly.